# Make Custom Post Type Child of Page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I need a post type to be the *child* of a page (actually of basically any other post type and itself), and it must apply to the CPT's taxonomies as well.

The general idea is to have a dynamic parent page in my options saved under `cpt_parent_page`.  Currently, my slug works out fine; in the admin, under my CPT taxomomies, I have the right links. However, when I view the taxonomy, I'm getting a 404. I'm pretty sure I'm just forgetting a very minor thing, but I need to remember said thing.

```
$cpt = 'book';
$cpt_singular = 'Book';
$cpt_plurial = 'Books';

/*
 * Register CPT
 */
$labels = array(
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New '.$cpt_singular,
    'all_items' => 'All '.$cpt_plurial,
    'edit_item' => 'Edit '.$cpt_singular,
    'name' => $cpt_singular,
    'name_admin_bar' => $cpt_singular,
    'new_item' => 'New '.$cpt_singular,
    'not_found' => 'No '.$cpt_singular.' found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No '.$cpt_plurial.' found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent '.$cpt_singular,
    'search_items' => 'Search '.$cpt_plurial,
    'view_item' => 'View '.$cpt_singular,
    'view_items' => 'View '.$cpt_plurial,
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'title' ),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => get_permalink( get_option('cpt_parent_page') ),
        'with_front' => false
    ),
);
register_post_type($cpt, $args);

/*
 * Register taxonomy
 */
register_taxonomy(
    $cpt_name, // Taxonomy name
    $cpt, // Associate taxonomy to this post type
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => $tax_name,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => get_permalink( get_option('cpt_parent_page') ),
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
    )
);
```

Comment: I assume `$cpt_name` is defined somewhere in the code, but you got a typo (in the question) - `$cpy` which I think should be `$cpt`. And what's an example value of `cpt_parent_page`?

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for your time, and for noticing the typo, which I've corrected. `` has an example value of `255`. As you can see, however, I use `get_permalink()` to get the format my URL rewrites.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't really notice the `get_permalink()` in the code. But you shouldn't use it.. please check my answer and let me know. (We can try something if you don't want the `/p` or `/t` ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the error `404` most likely because you haven't flushed the rewrite rules after you changed the option. But even if that's not the case, *make certain to always flush the rules after the option is changed* — simply visit the permalink settings page.

In addition to that, you shouldn't use `get_permalink()`, or that you should use the post *slug* and not its permalink URL. So make the following changes:

```
// Change this:
get_permalink( get_option('cpt_parent_page') )

// to this FOR THE POST TYPE:
get_post_field( 'post_name', get_option('cpt_parent_page') ) . '/p'

// or this FOR THE TAXONOMY:
get_post_field( 'post_name', get_option('cpt_parent_page') ) . '/t'
```

That should work; however, the `/p` and `/t` are necessary so that WordPress knows if the request is for a post or term (in a taxonomy) — without the `/p` or `/t`, the rewrite rules will clash and likely fail (e.g. a term request is confused as being a post or child Page request).

Comment: PS: It does *not* have to be the letter `p` or `t` - it can be any **unique text** you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the get_post_field method did do the trick as I now have my URL structure working and the taxonomy templates as well.